# Libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android

I am new to android.my project API Level 25. when I am running the project it shows `BUILD SUCCESSFUL..` but after 2 sec the app has stopped.

here it's my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.opent.fusedlocationproviderapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }}

dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

..........................................................

and am getting suggestion on line

> compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
>   All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification(mixing revisions can lead to runtime crashes)Found versions 25.3.1,25.2.0 .
>   examples inculde com.android.support:25.3.1
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drwabale:25.2.0.

what are the changes I need to do in Gradle?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
make it to compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.1'

Comment: make it  compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.2'

Comment: Show the crash log. Maybe that's not why it's crashing... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your google play services are using an older version and since they depend on the support library, you get a conflict.

Latest version is:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
```

Keep in mind that you only get a warning and no error for the version differencies, which means they could still work, but yet again it's better to stay up-to-date.

Comment: now when run my project event log shows "Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger. @Hristo Stoyanov

Comment: try clean - rebuild

Comment: now event log shows "Instant Run performed a full build and install since
   the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk.".@Hristo Stoyanov